# Libdvbcsa, missing header files

Tags: c, c-libraries

I have a problem i cannot solve. 
[Library repository](https://github.com/pingflood/libdvbcsa)
I am trying to run `test .c` files in this library, I have installed the files however when I run this on mac:

```
gcc testbitslice.c
```

I get this error

```
fatal error: dvbcsa_pv.h: No such file or directory
#include "dvbcsa_pv.h"
```

the `testbitslice.c` file calls the header files as follows

```
#include <dvbcsa/dvbcsa.h>
#include "dvbcsa_pv.h"
```

When I checked `urs/local/include` there are one file under `dvbcsa` folder which is `dvbcsa.h`. But there is no file called `dvbcsa_pv.h`. I don't understand the problem. I don't get error while installing with `./bootstrap` or `./configure` and `make`, `make install` commands.

Then, I manually copy/paste header files from package folder to `usr/local/include`, this time it gives error as

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Is the problem related to installation or something else? I would appreciate if you could help me

Comment: The problem is related to the search paths of the header files. But the first claim "..none of us knows anything about c..." gives an impression, that it is just worthless to try to help you with this error, since it will be just first one in an endless series of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the problem. I just had to show the library directory i want to use using:

```
-I/Users/bill/Desktop/libdvbcsa-master/src/dvbcsa
```

and it works.